# Proving that a grammar generates a language

Tags: computer-science, automata, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Since every context free grammar is equivalent to a Push down automaton, to show that a grammar $G$ generates a language $L$, is it sufficient to draw a PDA equivalent to $G$ and then show the PDA recognizes that language $L$?

Comment: I also read it this way the first time: "it is sufficient..." instead of "is it sufficient" ;-)

Comment: Sorry for bad punctuation. Edited.

Comment: It is sufficient to draw some PDA, **prove** that it is equivalent to $G$, and then show that this PDA recognizes $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work (if, as dtldarek said, you also prove that the automaton is actually equivalent to the grammar). But it doesn't *in general* feel like a productive strategy. Of course this can depend a lot on how the language $L$ is given -- but how many tools do you have which you can you can use on automatons, and *not* as well apply directly to the original grammar?